# How will my theme folder path in LIVE

Tags: php, expressionengine

Hi i have implemented my site in expression engine and in my local it is working fine but while I have moved my site to live my image uploading is not working due to theme_folder_url is in local,I have searched what it will be and found

```
$config['theme_folder_path'] = "/home/user/example.com/themes/";
```

What is the home , user....In live my folder structure is like public_html/themes/....So how can I give that path in my admin pannel.Anyone suggest me please

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to go to Admin => General Configuration in your control panel and change your path "URL to your "themes" folder" to wherever your themes folder is. It can be relative or absolute. You will also need to edit "Theme Folder Path" to your server path.

EDIT *** 
If you are not sure what your hosted server path is, you should be able to use something like this in the root folder and browse to it to gather the path.

```
<?php
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    echo "<p>Full path to this dir: " . $dir . "</p>";
?>
```